# WPF datagrid is not empty on instantiation causing error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am having an issue in a window for a WPF app I am creating. I am getting an error  when I tried to bind an ObservableCollection to a DataGrid. The thing that is confusing to me is that the datagrid seems like it is instantiating with a value already in it which causes the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="Store_grade_list_bulk_updater.POModifyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Store_grade_list_bulk_updater"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Modify Or Remove Grades &amp; PO Numbers" Height="450" Width="850"
    KeyDown="Escape_KeyDown">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="0,30,0,0">
        <TextBlock>
            Grade Code:
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="GradeBox"
            KeyDown="Grade_KeyDown">

        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock
            Margin="0,10,0,0">
            Purchase Order Code:
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="POBOx"
            KeyDown="PO_KeyDown">

        </TextBox>
        <Button
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            Content="Modify"
            Click="Modify_Click"/>
        <Button
            Margin="0,15,0,0"
            Content="Close Window"
            Click="CloseWindow_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid
            Grid.Column="0"
            x:Name="Modify_GradeList"
            Margin="10"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            SelectionChanged="GradeList_Select">
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Grade}"/>

        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid
            Grid.Column="1"
            x:Name="Modify_PO_List"
            Margin="10"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            SelectionChanged="PO_List_Select">
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PO Code" Binding="{Binding PO_Code}" Width="3*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Country}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stores" Binding="{Binding Store_Count}" Width="*"/>

        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="Store_List"
            Margin="10,0,10,10"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Store_Code}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Store_Name}" Width="4*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Grade_Rank}" Width="*"/>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Store_grade_list_bulk_updater
{

public partial class POModifyWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.Template> modify_grades = new ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.Template>();
        public ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.PO> modify_po_list = new ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.PO>();
        public ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.Grade> modify_grade_details = new ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.Grade>();

        public POModifyWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWindow tempMain = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;

            // This returns "1"
            MessageBox.Show(Modify_GradeList.Items.Count.ToString());

            // Troubleshooting step
            Modify_GradeList.ItemsSource = modify_grades;
            // End troubleshooting

            modify_grades = tempMain.gradelist;
            Modify_GradeList.ItemsSource = modify_grades;
            Modify_PO_List.ItemsSource = modify_po_list;
            Store_List.ItemsSource = modify_grade_details;
        }

        public void Modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void CloseWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow tempMain = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            tempMain.ReceiveTemplates(modify_grades);
            Close();

        }


        public void GradeList_Select (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            modify_po_list = Modify_GradeList.SelectedItem as ObservableCollection<GradeTemplate.PO>;
            Modify_PO_List.ItemsSource = modify_po_list;
            GradeTemplate.Template textbox_temp = Modify_GradeList.SelectedItem as GradeTemplate.Template;
            GradeBox.Text = textbox_temp.Grade;
        }

        public void PO_List_Select(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        public void Escape_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                MainWindow tempMain = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
                tempMain.ReceiveTemplates(modify_grades);
                Close();
            }
        }

        public void Grade_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                TextBox s = e.Source as TextBox;
                s.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Down));
            }

        }

        public void PO_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                GradeBox.Clear();
                POBOx.Clear();
                TextBox s = e.Source as TextBox;
                s.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Up));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Originally I thought it was due to trying to bind a collection with objects already in it, although this already worked in another window, but when I added in the line of code marked as troubleshooting it still causes the error. From what I can tell it seems to be related to the XAML somehow, as the error only started occurring after I added in the text columns to try and have a consistent format, but I cannot tell where it is occurring or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a column in DataGrid, you need to have `<DataGrid.Columns>`
and inside you need to define the columns.

by directly, defining the column, it assumes it has data, so it thinks you are providing the `itemSource` twice and thus the error :-  `Collection must be empty before using`ItemsSource

```
        <DataGrid
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="Modify_GradeList"
        Margin="10"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        SelectionChanged="GradeList_Select">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Grade Code" Binding="{Binding Path=Grade}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Do the same for other DataGrid.

Comment: @HiKaizer checkout the solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had been trying to figure it out for a while! I wasn't expecting the XAML issue to cause that behaviour but at least it had a simple answer.